# eclipse the module is not a war module

Tags: eclipse, web-deployment

I am working on a web project with eclipse, I have Jetty to run this application locally.
Now I want to export it as a war file, during the process, it says "the module is not a war module", and that's it.
So I searched, finding no useful tips.
Please help me out!

Comment: Did you select dynamic web project while creating new project from eclipse?

Comment: I imported it from svn

Comment: Change project facets solved my problem.